# Path creation for testing files that stays the same on all users using the repo

Tags: file, testing

I am new to developing and testing. I am currently writing tests in java for an app that has a multiple other devs working on it. Part of the tests is test methods that create, delete and write to files. However I am creating and deleting them on my local device with a local path, obviously this will fail the minute someone else tries running these tests on their devices with the same path. How do I get around this?
I havent found any relevant solutions online yet.
Thanks!